# How to plot vectors from capscale analysis in ggplot2?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, extract, vegan

I have generated a capscale model of presence-absence community composition data using capscale in vegan. I am able to use the following code to produce a plot using base R

```
(SOR.capscale <- capscale(SOR ~ df.meta.clin.week.snake$copy.num + df.meta.clin.week.snake$exp.time, df.otus.clin.week.snake.nonzero)) #specify model
plot(SOR.capscale, main = "Capscale Analysis", xlab = "CAP1", ylab = "CAP2")
points(SOR.capscale, col = expgroup)
ordihull(SOR.capscale, expgroup, col = c("black", "red"), label = FALSE, display = "sites")
```

This generates the following visualization

[image]

I have used the following code to extract the CAP values from the capscale model to plot them in ggplot

```
x <- as.data.frame(scores(SOR.capscale, display = "sites"))
df.pred.clin.week.snake$CAP1 <- x$CAP1
df.pred.clin.week.snake$CAP2 <- x$CAP2
```

I have used this data to generate a plot in ggplot with the listed code

```
ggplot(df.pred.clin.week.snake, aes(x= CAP1, y= CAP2, color = expgroup)) + 
  stat_ellipse(aes(fill = expgroup), geom = "polygon", alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_classic() + 
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(-20, 20), ylim=c(-6.5, 15)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype="dotted") + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype="dotted") +
  labs(color = "Experimental Treatment", fill = "Experimental Treatment") +
  ggtitle("Capscale Analysis") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
  ylab("CAP2") + 
  xlab("CAP1")
```

[image]

My question is how would I extract the vector information from the capscale analysis model in such a way that I am then be able to plot them using ggplot? Thank you greatly!

Answer (score 1):

In capscale the information is there to tell you where the arrows come from , generally SOR.capscale$CCA$biplot - whatever those numbers are you can plug them in:

`plot + geom_segment(aes(x = 0.0, y =0.0,xend = 10.9 , yend = -0.01), arrow =arrow())+ geom_segment(aes(x = 0.0, y =0.0, xend = 0.01, yend = 10.1), arrow =arrow())`

or whatever your actual numbers are.